# useState not updating socket value

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-state

In the following code from my Socket context file the useState is not updating the socket value. But I saw that newSocket is getting a not null value. Can anyone please help?

```
import React,{useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const SocketContext = React.createContext({
    socket:null
});

const SocketContextProvider = (props)=>{
    const [socket,setSocket] = useState(null);

    
    let id = props.id;
    useEffect(()=>{
        let newSocket = io('http://localhost:5000', { query: { id }});

        setSocket((p)=>{
            return  newSocket;
        });

        console.log(''+socket);

        return (() => {
            newSocket.close();
        })

    }, [props.id]);

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{socket:socket}}>
            {props.children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default SocketContext;
export {SocketContextProvider};
```

Comment: React.setState is async, does not update the value immediately

Comment: @glinda93 thanks. Can you please give a eg. showing what can be done to update the state immediately

Comment: put console log ouside useEffect, starting will till print null, as soon as react has rendered once ,useEffect will run and you will get socket in console log

Comment: if you want imidiate value, then you can set initial value of socket io like so 
`const [socket , setSocket ] = useState( io('http://localhost:5000', { query: { props.id }}) )`

Comment: @AbdulKàbéèr thanks